# How to execute TF commands in Jenkins

Tags: python, visual-studio, jenkins, tfs, tf-cli

> I am trying to merge a branch continuously ( every 5 minute) using
>   Jenkins. I am using Visual Studio, and so using the TFS tf command merge,
>   i do this

```
tf merge $/ServerFolderA  $/ServerFolderB / recursive
```

> I also tried to add, checkout, checkin from the locals to the servers,
>   but it did not work either:

```
cd "C:\Users\vXXX\Desktop\ServerB" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get "$/ServerA"


cd "C:\Users\vXXX\Desktop\ServerB" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" checkout"$/ServerA"


cd "C:\Users\vXXX\Desktop\ServerB" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" checkin"$/ServerA"
```

> However, it does not work, i get the following error for the first example:
>
> 'tf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>   I also get a similar error for the second one.
>
> thanks for your help

Comment: sounds like 1) tf isn't installed on the CI slave where your job is running (check where your job is running and jump onto that machine to check) or 2) it's not in the PATH (try specifying the full path to tf to check this).

Comment: Did you install VS 2015 on your Jenkins sever?

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: Can you see "tf.exe" in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\" on Jenkins server?

Comment: yes i can as well